# Color on current page (asp.NET masterpage)

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm going to deliver a website for a school-project tomorrow and while I'm going over bugs I found out that to increase the level of user-friendliness I should change the color of the active page in the header.

I know well how i can do this in a basic html-site, but now I've used asp.NET master-page and after what I understand it would be a bit different this time since I do not have access to the links from other stylesheets than the masterpage.css

So to simplify the question:

I got a:hover on the links to change color when i hover over them, but want the link of the active page to be in another color to show the user where he is at all times (not a:visited).

Here is my code:

```
    <nav class="navMain">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="a_home" href="Default.aspx">Hjem</a></li>
                <li><a href="Kampanje.aspx">Om konkurransen</a></li>
                <li><a href="Default.aspx"><img id="navPic" src="Pictures/header/Munch150.png" alt="munch logo" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="Bildegalleri.aspx">Bidrag</a></li>
                <li><a href="Infoside.aspx">Om oss</a></li>
            </ul>
     </nav>
```

And css:

```
    .navMain {
position: relative;
bottom: 43px;
right: 80px;
height: 25px;
width: 1000px;
z-index: 100;
```

}

```
.navMain #navPic {
    position: relative;
    top: 93px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 125px;
}

.navMain a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
     .navMain a:hover {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }



.navMain li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5em;
}

.navMain ul {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Hoping for fast response, thanks!

Comment: You need to do that with programming, ether when you render the links on code behind to give him a different css style, ether using javascript on client side

Answer (score 0):

use your CSS like this

```
a:active { color: #666666; }
```